# machine learning model different inputs

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

i have dataset, the data set consists of : Date , ID ( the id of the event ), number_of_activities, running_sum ( the running_sum is the running sum of activities by id).
this is a part of my data :

---

```
    date       |   id (id of the event)   |   number_of_activities  |    running_sum  |

   2017-01-06  |   156                    |                   1     |             1   |

   2017-04-26  |   156                    |                   1     |             2   |

   2017-07-04  |   156                    |                   2     |              4  | 

   2017-01-19  |   175                    |                   1     |             1   |

   2017-03-17  |   175                    |                   3     |             4   |

   2017-04-27  |   221                    |                   3     |             3   |

   2017-05-05  |   221                    |                   7     |             10  |

   2017-05-09  |   221                    |                   10    |             20  |

   2017-05-19  |   221                    |                   1     |             21  |

   2017-09-03  |   221                    |                   2     |             23  |
```

the goal for me is to predict the future number of activities in a given event, my question : can i train my model on all the dataset ( all the events) to predict the next one, if so how? because there are inequalities in the number of inputs ( number of rows for each event is different ), and is it possible to exploit the date data as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. But alot of more information is needed, which you know yourself the best.
I guess we are talking about timeseries here as you want to predict the future.
You might want to have alook at recurrent-neural nets and LSTMs:

An Recurrent-layer takes a timeseries as input and outputs a vector, which contains the compressed information about the whole timeseries. So lets take event 156, which has 3 steps:
The event is your features, which has 3 timesteps. Each timestep has different numbers of activities (or features). To solve this, just use the maximum amount of features occuring and add a padding value (most often simply zero) so they all have the samel length. Then you have a shape, which is suitable for a recurrent neural Net (where LSTMS are currently a good choice)

**Update**

You said in the comments, that using padding is not option for you, let me try to convince you. LSTMs are good at situations, where the sequence length is different long. However, for this to work you also need to have longer sequences, what the model can learn its patterns from. What I want to say, when some of your sequences have only a few timesteps like 3, but you have other with 50 and more timesteps, the model might have its difficulties to predict these correct, as you have to specify, which timestep you want to use. So either, you prepare your data differently for a clear question, or you dig deeper into the topic using **SequenceToSequence** Learning, which is very good at computing sequences with different lenghts. For this you will need to set up a **Encoder-Decoder** network.

The Encoder squashs the whole sequence into one vector, whatever length it is. This one vector is compressed in a way, that it contains the information of the sequence only in one vector.

The Decoder then learns to use this vector for predicting the next outputs of the sequences. This is a known technique for machine-translation, but is suitable for any kind of sequence2sequence tasks. So I would recommend you to create such a Encoder-Decoder network, which for sure will improve your results. Have a look at this [tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-encoder-decoder-model-sequence-sequence-prediction-keras/), which might help you further

Comment: hello, thank you so much for your answer, but i was actually asking if there was a method for making the inputs dynamique so the lstm could take them, padding or cutting the series is not an option for me because with padding i have a huge diffrence between some series, wich adds an incredible amount of data and throws my predictions off, and with reducing it i don't obtain what i want, this is actually the tutoriel i fllowed for doing so if anyone is looking  : https://machinelearningmastery.com/data-preparation-variable-length-input-sequences-sequence-prediction/

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic? Which part of the input shall be dynamic?

Comment: the length of the rows : for exemple : event with id 156 has 3 occurences , but event with id 221 has 5 occurences